# Make JsonNode Serializable

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

This seems to be simple but I failed to get a serialized JsonNode deserialized. Here is my test class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private String string;
    private transient JsonNode jsonNode;

    public Foo(String string, JsonNode jsonNode) {
        this.string = string;
        this.jsonNode = jsonNode;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        if (this.jsonNode != null) out.writeObject((new ObjectMapper()).writeValueAsBytes(this.jsonNode));
//        out.writeObject(this.jsonNode.textValue());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        this.jsonNode = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(in, JsonNode.class);
    }
}
```

When I tried to deserialize I got this error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
```

Here is the unit test

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.*;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testSerialization() {
        JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory = new JsonNodeFactory(false);
        ObjectNode node = nodeFactory.objectNode();
        ObjectNode child = nodeFactory.objectNode(); // the child
        child.put("message", "test");
        node.put("notification", child);

        Foo foo = new Foo("Bar", node);

        String fileName = "foo.ser";
        try (
                OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
                ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        ){
            output.writeObject(foo);
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }

        Foo fooNew = null;

        //deserialize the ser file
        try(
                InputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
                ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream (buffer);
        ){
            //deserialize the Object
            fooNew = (Foo) input.readObject();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        assertEquals(foo, fooNew);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just serialize to JSON? Why do you want to serialize JsonNode itself?

Comment: Another suggestion is to always operate (create, serialize, deserialize) `JsonNode` via `ObjectMapper`: `JsonNodeFactory` is only meant for internal (re)configuration and overrides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your read and write operations are not matched.

On the write side you use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object)` to write a `byte[]` containing the serialized JSON content. On the read side you try to read raw bytes off the stream with `ObjectMapper.readValue(InputStream, Class)` when you actually need to read a `byte[]` object first as that is what you wrote and then use `ObjectMapper.readValue(byte[], Class)`.

Alternatively and probably a better solution is you could use `ObjectMapper.writeValue(OutputStream, Object)` instead on the write side.

Try this:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    if(jsonNode == null){
        out.writeBoolean(false);
    } else {
        out.writeBoolean(true);
        new ObjectMapper().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false).writeValue(out, jsonNode);
    }
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    if(in.readBoolean()){
        this.jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false).readValue(in, JsonNode.class);
    }     
}
```

Comment: I chose the later, which looks a lot more symmetrical.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, just as I thought it is working. I get another error java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: misc.test.SerializationTest.  The code is in https://github.com/songyangster/vertx-in-springboot/blob/master/src/test/java/misc/test/SerializationTest.java And if I comment out out.defaultWriteObject();, I got java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: You should probably open another question, as the `NotSerializableException` is unrelated to the original issue. That being said, a `NotSerializableException` occurs when one tries to serialize an object that does not implement `java.io.Serializable`.  `misc.test.SerializationTest` likely does not implement `java.io.Serializable`

Comment: That was my bad. NonSerializable was due to inner class. Now I've moved it out and only see java.io.IOException: Stream Closed error. Please see the updated code. The debug shows readObject actually can deserialize both string and joshed.  But after that, the exception happens.  Perhaps there is some improper closing of the InputObjectStream?

Comment: @datree Check out the code example added. The issue is that the ObjectMapper closes the stream by default, that feature needs to be turned off.

Comment: Great!  Just what I want!  Thx!

Comment: Keep in mind that for recent versions of Jackson, `ObjectOutputStream` has to be cast to an `OutputStream` in order for the snippet to compile, due to a signature conflict between an overloaded method that takes a `DataOutput`.