# Jackson ObjectMapper in readObject causes IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to make JsonNode inside a class Serializable.  But when I ran my test code, I got the Exception when Jackson ObjectMapper is used in readObject.

java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
...

Here is the code
https://github.com/songyangster/vertx-in-springboot/tree/master/src/test/java/misc/test

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private String string;
    private transient String s2;
    private transient JsonNode jsonNode;

    public Foo(String string, String s2, JsonNode jsonNode) {
        this.string = string;
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.jsonNode = jsonNode;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeObject(s2);
        if (this.jsonNode != null) (new ObjectMapper()).writeValue(out, jsonNode);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        s2 = (String) in.readObject();
        if (in.available() > 0) this.jsonNode = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(in, JsonNode.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Foo)) return false;

        Foo foo = (Foo) o;

        if (string != null ? !string.equals(foo.string) : foo.string != null) return false;
        if (s2 != null ? !s2.equals(foo.s2) : foo.s2 != null) return false;
        return !(jsonNode != null ? !jsonNode.equals(foo.jsonNode) : foo.jsonNode != null);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = string != null ? string.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (s2 != null ? s2.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (jsonNode != null ? jsonNode.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}

public class SerializationTest {
    @Test
    public void testSerialization() {
        JsonNode node = (new ObjectMapper()).valueToTree("Test");

        // This one succeeds
        runTest(null);

        // This on fails
        runTest(node);
    }

    private void runTest(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        Foo foo = new Foo("Bar", "s2", jsonNode);

        String fileName = "foo.ser";
        try (
                OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
                ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        ){
            output.writeObject(foo);
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }

        Foo fooNew = null;

        //deserialize the ser file
        try(
                InputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
                ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream (buffer);
        ){
            //deserialize the Object
            fooNew = (Foo) input.readObject();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Assert.assertEquals(foo, fooNew);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not a solution, but I found a workaround, by converting JsonNode to String and back with

        String jsonString = (new ObjectMapper()).writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
        out.writeObject(jsonString);

and

        String jsonString = (String) in.readObject();
        jsonNode = (new ObjectMapper()).readTree(jsonString);

Comment: This is resolved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861354/make-jsonnode-serializable

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why are you trying to do this, why would you like to have JSonNode in your class as serializable? 
 Use Jackson in order to serialize/deserialize data structures, not JSon "elements".

Comment: This is to use standard java serialization to write object to file and later deserialize back to the same object.  If there is another way to serialize/deserialize JsonNode, then all the better.

Comment: Why does the original contain JsonNode? Can you explain?